# Python3: Type Hint, How to use TypeVar while defining a class whithing a Generic class

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I am trying to use the `TypeVar` T inside Generic class: in a `_dataclass_helper`

MyPy error in the "value"

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
from dataclasses import dataclass


_T = TypeVar("_T")


class Base(Generic[_T]):
    @dataclass
    class _dataclass_helper:
        value: _T  #<<--- mypy: Type variable "HW.DC_ValueGeneric._T" is unbound 
        string: str

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    # using _dataclass_helper in the code
```

I have tried to have `_dataclass_helper` as Generic,
or either to define the `_dataclass_helper` outside the scope of Base...
But both miss the target

Answer (score 2):

Let inner classes inherit `Generic` instead of outer classes:

```
class Base:
    @dataclass
    class _dataclass_helper(Generic[_T]):
        value: _T
        string: str

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

According to your comments, what you want is to determine the generics of internal classes while determining the generics of external classes, but the internal class and the external class are two independent classes, and there is no connection between them. One possible option is to use a method to build instances of internal classes:

```
_T = TypeVar("_T")
_S = TypeVar("_S")


class Base(Generic[_T]):

    @dataclass
    class _dataclass_helper(Generic[_S]):
        value: _S
        string: str

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def helper(self, value: _T, string: str) -> _dataclass_helper[_T]:
        return self._dataclass_helper(value, string)
```

Comment: Thanks - but 
The _T is needed both in Base and in _helper 
AND it needs to be the same Type

Comment: @TalOmer You didn't explain this in the question so that I took it as a mistake of yours. Your solution is appropriate.

Comment: @TalOmer The same type cannot be achieved. An internal class has no connection with its external classes, but you can dynamically build it and bind it to the instance of the external class.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#scoping-rules-for-type-variables

quoting

> A generic class nested in another generic class cannot use same type variables. The scope of the type variables of the outer class doesn’t cover the inner one:

```py
T = TypeVar('T')
S = TypeVar('S')

class Outer(Generic[T]):
    class Bad(Iterable[T]):       # Error
        ...
    class AlsoBad:
        x = None  # type: List[T] # Also an error

    class Inner(Iterable[S]):     # OK
        ...
    attr = None  # type: Inner[T] # Also OK
```